# Prevent the deletion of Account which have related contact records having primary_contact__c check box = yes . (Salesforce trigger)

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

how do I know how many related contact record having primary_contact__c == true?

```
trigger AccountTrigger_1 on Account (before delete)
{
    list <account> acclist = [select id,(select id, primary_contact__c from contacts) from account where id in : trigger.old];
    for (account acc1 : trigger.old){
        for(account acc2 :acclist  ){
            
            if(acc1.contacts.size() > 0){
                acc1.adderror('you can not delete account');
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there but that double for loop will explode if you ever do mass delete, 200x200 records to loop is bit evil.

This should work bit better.

```apex
trigger AccountTrigger_1 on Account (before delete)
{
    Map<Id, Account> checks = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id,
        (SELECT Id
        FROM Contacts
        WHERE Primary_Contact__c = true
        LIMIT 1)
        FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN :trigger.old
    ]);

    for (account acc1 : trigger.old){
        Account check = checks.get(acc1.Id);
        if(!check.Contacts.isEmpty()){
            acc1.adderror('you can not delete account');
        }
    }  
}
```